# Finding another Polygon with same properties

Tags: education, polygons

Imagine a square of length 1. So the area is also 1 and the perimeter is 4. 
Now the question is find another polygon with the exact same properties.

Comment: Any thoughts?  I suggest:  first show that there is no such triangle.  Then look at pentagons.

Comment: I thought that this could be made possible simply by editing the 1*1 square in some clever manner

Comment: The square has the largest area amongst four sided figures with fixed perimeter.  Can't do much with four sided figures.

Comment: I know. By editing, I meant cutting up parts trying to create different polygons like that.